# Client-side validation error message is hidden for 'Password' field (ASP.NET Core Razor page)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a auto-generated (by template) code in Razor page responsible for creating a new user. In this form I have a client-site validation which partially works. First field in form (email) shows correct error message, but second field (password) generates HTML code which is hidden.

[Rendered HTML:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1yyj.png)

Input model:

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email jest wymagany")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Pole Email nie jest prawidłowym adresem e-mail")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Hasło jest wymagane")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "{0} musi mieć co najmniej {2} znaków.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Hasło")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Potwierdź hasło")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Oba hasła muszą być takie same")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Akceptuje")]
    [ConsentRequired()]
    public bool ConsentAgreement { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `.cshtml` view file:

```
<div>
    <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined register-form-component" style="width: 60%; display: block; margin: auto" asp-for="Input.Password">
        <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="register-password-id">Hasło</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="password" asp-for="Input.Password" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="register-password-id">
    </label>
    <div class="mdc-text-field-helper-line register-form-component" asp-validation-for="Input.Password">
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="mdc-text-field-helper-text mdc-text-field-helper-text--validation-msg"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined register-form-component" style="width: 60%; display: block; margin: auto" asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword">
        <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="confirm-password-id">Potwierdź hasło</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="password" asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="confirm-password-id">
    </label>
    <div class="mdc-text-field-helper-line register-form-component" asp-validation-for="Input.Password">
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="mdc-text-field-helper-text mdc-text-field-helper-text--validation-msg"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to change input model (changes in data annotations) but it didn't work. Also, I was trying some CSS stuff but also with no success.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: i dunno, but it looks like you have `asp-validation-for="Input.Password"` instead of `asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"` in one place

Comment: yeah having those two asp-validation-for's is probably mucking things up.  Include the label, input and span inside one div.  Looks like the browser is also choking on that span's class.  I'd just set that to class="text-danger" just to rule that out while debugging this.  The span's containing div also seems to be set as hidden so getting rid of it should help.